# Discord py and dropdown menus

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I made a dropdown menus. The second menu I have is ephemeral, but when I close this message and select a choice from the old menu, they send me two menus, then 3 and so on. Also the first menu is duplicated. I diactivated ephemeral, but I need this option. [There are 3 menus in the picture.  The first one is called after the command, 2 and 3 after the selection in the first one.  But the second menu is a duplicate of the first one, which I don't need.  I need to set this up so that the second menu is not sent again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PWl3.jpg)

```
class NewSelect(discord.ui.Select):

  def __init__(self):

    options = [

    discord.SelectOption(label='Ssssss', value='h'),

    discord.SelectOption(label='2ssss', value='54'),

    discord.SelectOption(label='sfsfsf', value='ghghhh')

    ]

    super().__init__(options=options, placeholder='What ',)

  

  async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

    ...

class MtView(discord.ui.View):

  answer1 = None  

  answer2 = None

  @discord.ui.select(

    placeholder = 'Выберите отдел',

    options = [

    discord.SelectOption(label='Дискорд отдел ', value='discord'),

    discord.SelectOption(label='Модераторский отдел ', value='game'),

    ]

  )

  

  async def what_category(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select_item = discord.ui.Select):

    self.answer1 = select_item.values

    self.children[0].disabled = False 

    view2 = self.add_item(NewSelect())

    await interaction.response.send_message(view=view2, ephemeral=True)

    

    

@aclient.command()

async def test(ctx):

  view=MtView()

  await ctx.send(view=view)
```

Testing, search information, write code, nothing help me

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be this line:

```
view2 = self.add_item(NewSelect())
```

Every time a select menu is selected, it triggers `what_category`, and responds to the interaction with the previous view but adds another select menu to `view2` every single time.

Possible Fix:

```
class NewSelect(discord.ui.Select):

  def __init__(self):

    options = [

    discord.SelectOption(label='Ssssss', value='h'),

    discord.SelectOption(label='2ssss', value='54'),

    discord.SelectOption(label='sfsfsf', value='ghghhh')

    ]

    super().__init__(options=options, placeholder='What ',)

  

  async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

    ...

class MtView(discord.ui.View):

  answer1 = None  

  answer2 = None

  @discord.ui.select(

    placeholder = 'Выберите отдел',

    options = [

    discord.SelectOption(label='Дискорд отдел ', value='discord'),

    discord.SelectOption(label='Модераторский отдел ', value='game'),

    ]

  )

  

  async def what_category(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select_item = discord.ui.Select):

    self.answer1 = select_item.values

    self.children[0].disabled = False 

    del view2

    view2 = self.add_item(NewSelect())

    await interaction.response.send_message(view=view2, ephemeral=True)

    

    

@aclient.command()

async def test(ctx):

  view=MtView()

  await ctx.send(view=view)
```

Cheers, Eric